# Truncate time from datetime in PRESTO

Tags: date, datetime, truncate, presto

I've a requirement to truncate time from datetime in Presto. 
I noticed that I cannot use Trunc() function which is used in Redshift to achieve the same.

date_trunc() returns a timestamp again resetting to the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Cast**](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html) the datetime to date

```
CAST(x AS DATE)

date(x) -- This is an alias for CAST(x AS DATE).
```

**IF** the date/time values to be converted are held as strings then such a conversion might fail; in which using `TRY_CAST()` is recommended as this returns NULL if the conversion fails.

Comment: `try_cast` is potentially useful for a cast that can fail, like `varchar` to `number` -- not every text is all-digits, thus this cast is a partial function. Cast from `timestamp` to `date` cannot fail, since every timestamp has a date component, this cast is a function (not partial function).
TL;DR `try_cast` is not useful in this context.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen the mention of `try_cast()` in my answer was aimed at anyone you might (unfortunately) have to deal with date/time data stored as strings. So I have made that more obvious I hope. Thanks.